# Not able configure AzureAD connect - getting a prompt to enter Synchronization account password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was trying to setup AzureAD connect between an onprem lab and azuread. I have done this countless of times, however for the first this is is happening. As soon as I am done entering all the configuration details and click configure. The installer first creates a synchronization account on AzureAD and then prompts me for credentials for that account. From my experience this should not happen. Is there any configuration I should check on AzureAD side? I tried doing this with a different AzureAD tenant and I was successful. Not sure what I should look for.
[image: AzureAD Connect password]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please confirm if you have any MFA policy being applied for all accounts? This issue normally happens when you have a conditional access policy that is applied for all the accounts, so, this account got automatically created and got the policy applied. If so, please exclude this account from that conditional policy and the issue should be solved.